# how to execute share point server via link in internet explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, sharepoint, hyperlink

```
https://login:password1@sharepoint.server.com/
```

It works in Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't in IE.. how it can be solved?

It works in Internet Explorer:

```
https://                sharepoint.server.com/
```

When it's loaded, I just get a window where I need to enter login and password.

It doesn't work in Internet Explorer (it should be automatically logged in. this solution work everywhere except Internet Explorer):

```
https://login:password1@sharepoint.server.com/
```

Comment: Do you really have to use the "login:password1" thing at the beginning of your url? That format is used with FTP protocol, I haven't seen any app using that for http. For HTTP, we have different Authentication mechanizms which allow you to write username and password on a specific login screen. URL is not the place for that.

Comment: I need to use it to get access to the sharepoint server. This login and password are the same as it's in the application. I just use some information from sharepoint server in order to show it in the application.

Comment: My application uses links on the sharepoint forms which are showen in my application

Comment: I see. What is the IE version you're using?

Comment: So, in the case, when I don't use link with login and pass, I need to enter them manually when log in window appears.. And, in case, when I use link login and password, it's logged in automatically.. but it works in chrome, not in Internet explorer

Comment: I understand your problem. Can you tell me which IE are you using? 5, 6, 9, 10, Edge???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I saw that this feature is disabled in IE after version 7 bacouse of the misuse of embedded authentication information in urls (I guess you understand when people start bookmarking and saving URLs with their passwords on it on a plain text environment).

You can change the setting by editing registry though.

In the http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489 reference

The following workaround is given:

To disable the new default behavior in Windows Explorer and Internet Explorer, create iexplore.exe and explorer.exe DWORD values in one of the following registry keys and set their value data to 0.

For all users of the program, set the value in the following registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE`

For the current user of the program only, set the value in the following registry key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE`

Also, if you don't want to mess with registry, on other way is to use this microsoft tool. I really didn't use it myself, probably it's outdated. But putting here anyway for reference.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489#FixItForMeAlways

Comment: So, if I need to deliver stable version to the final customers, then I need to ask them to make some changes in the registry.. yeah?

Comment: No, you really should understand why Microsoft removed this feature and accept it as a bad practice and not use it at all. Or if you really need to, let your users do that on chrome or firefox. After understanding why this feature is removed from the recent versions of IE, I totally get why I don't see any applications which lets the use of "login:password" format.

Comment: And what's a solution in my case? I still need to use some data from sharepoint server.. and mostly final customers use IE..

Comment: They will enter their credentials when the page will promt them. As the rest of the world is doing, I guess :) You should understand one thing though. If it's forbidden by microsoft, you can be sure that there is a good reason behind it (bad practices, security problems, etc...). You should accept it as a fact of life and move on.